# Show hide / toggle indivdualy not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code  which currently opens all when i click readmore. How can i make them open individually?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".readmore-content").hide();
    $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
        $(".readmore-content").toggle("slow");
       e.preventDefault();  
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="result-b">
    <h4> lorem ipsum </h4>
    <p>lorem ip sum soem <a href= "#" class="read-more">Read more</a> </p>
    <div class="readmore-content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    lorem ipsum
    </div>

</div>
<div class="result-b">
    <h4> lorem ipsum </h4>
    <p>lorem ip sum soem <a href= "#" class="read-more">Read more</a> </p>
    <div class="readmore-content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    lorem ipsum
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the current element context with `$(this)`
2. Navigate up to parent `p` element with `parent()`
3. Navigate to sibling with `next()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".readmore-content").hide();
  $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent('p').next(".readmore-content").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result-b">
  <h4> lorem ipsum </h4>
  <p>lorem ip sum soem <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a> 
  </p>
  <div class="readmore-content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>

</div>
<div class="result-b">
  <h4> lorem ipsum </h4>
  <p>lorem ip sum soem <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a> 
  </p>
  <div class="readmore-content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>

</div>
```